# Disable date/process ID in xcode output

Tags: ios, xcode

How can I remove date and process ID from output window in XCode? They only take up a lot of space without real value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this macro, this will override the default behavior of NSLog,

```
#define NSLog(STRING, ...) printf("%s\n", [[NSString stringWithFormat:STRING, ##__VA_ARGS__] UTF8String]);
```

Comment: I like to add `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` to automatically add class/method info.

Comment: wojtek asked this question, i tried to give an answer. Few asks how to add, line number, method name etc etc...

Comment: Anaoop great answer. I would just like to add comment that ending ';' could be dropped since it is not needed and it can generate build error in one liner if-else statement.